# TypeError at /accounts/add_rent_payment/1363902a-c341-4883-84ee-1e12156b0381

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have two model namely Receipt and RentPayment. What I want to achieve is for me to create a Receipt, I want to redirect to a RentPayment form with a initial value of the recently saved receipt in the receipt field.

models.py

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    receipt_number = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    month_paid = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True,blank=True,choices=MONTHS)
    balance_due = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    total_rent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True,blank=True)

class RentPayment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    receipt = models.ForeignKey(Receipt, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    amount_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    payment_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    next_payment_due = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
def createReceipt(request,pk):  
    property_entity = Property.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ReceiptForm(initial={'property' :property_entity})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReceiptForm(request.POST, initial={'property' :property_entity})
        if form.is_valid():
            receipt_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            receipt_obj.property = property_entity
            receipt_obj.save()

            return redirect('add_rent_payment', receipt_pk=receipt_obj.id)
    else:
        ReceiptForm()

    context = {'property_entity' :property_entity,
            'form' :form
            }

    return render(request,"accounting/receipt.html",context)

def add_rent_payment(request, pk):
    receipt = Receipt.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rent_payment_form = RentPaymentForm(request.POST)
        if rent_payment_form.is_valid():
            rent_payment = rent_payment_form.save(commit=False)
            rent_payment.receipt = receipt
            rent_payment.save()
            return redirect('property_list')
    else:
        rent_payment_form = RentPaymentForm()
    context = {
        'receipt': receipt,
        'rent_payment_form': rent_payment_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounting/add_rent_payment.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('receipt/<str:pk>', views.createReceipt, name="receipt"),
    path('add_rent_payment/<str:receipt_pk>', views.add_rent_payment, name="add_rent_payment")
]
```

Comment: So is it not working or showing some error?

Comment: when I save the Receipt Form, instead of redirecting to the RentPayment Form, it's returning the following error, 
add_rent_payment() got an unexpected keyword argument 'receipt_pk'

Comment: So it should be `def add_rent_payment(request,  receipt_pk):` instead of `def add_rent_payment(request, pk):` as you are passing `receipt_pk` in URL pattern, if works kindly tell me I will make Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing `receipt_pk` as URL parameter so the `add_rent_payment` view should also recieve it as an argument instead of `pk`, like so:

```py
def add_rent_payment(request, receipt_pk):
    #...
```

> **Note:** Always add `/` at the end of every route so in urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('receipt/<str:pk>/', views.createReceipt, name="receipt"),
    path('add_rent_payment/<str:receipt_pk>/', views.add_rent_payment, name="add_rent_payment")
]
```